# Object is marked "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is not initialized in this constructor

Tags: java

I have the following Object

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class SomeObject {
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private int someCount;

    public int getSomeCount() {
        return someCount;
    }

    public void setSomeCount(final int someCount) {
        this.someCount = someCount;
    }

    public SomeObject(final int someCount) {
        this.someCount = someCount;
    }
}
```

But I get

> "someCount" is marked "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is
>   not initialized in this constructor.

and it's pointing to the constructor. I'm passing an item into the constructor. How do I fix this

Comment: you don't need the `@Valid` annotation. also, you can probably resolve the problem by explicitly declaring the default no-arg constructor and assigning it a bogus value e.g. `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a primitive type `int` here. It can't be null. Rather I would suggest you using `@Min(0)` validator instead. If you really need to have null passed in as a value then use a wrapper `Integer` instead. For that you can have a null check as above. I don't recommend this approach though.

Answer (score 0):

"javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is not initialized in this constructor

We have recently encountered this issue in our sonar build.

To fix this issue we initialized the non-null field at the time of deceleration itself.

Consider below code.

```
public class Dummy {

    @NotNull(message = "Dummy field cannot be null")
    private Integer dummyField = -1; // Any default value


    public Dummy(Integer dummyField) {
        this.dummyField = dummyField;
    }

    public Integer getDummyField() {
        return dummyField;
    }

    public void setDummyField(Integer dummyField) {
        this.dummyField = dummyField;
    }


}
```

Comment: If it can't be null, why should you annotate it with `@NotNull`?

Comment: Actually you are correct Clijsters. 
SonarQube didn't like if you annotate the field Notnull and you don't initialize it. So in order to make the code compliance with Sonar quality, I can add a default value at the time of deceleration. However it will make Notnull annotation redundant