# What is the best way to handle SonarQube error "javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, struts2-jsr303-plugin

Consider the below code. When I analyze the code for sonar rule, it complains about *"javax.validation.constraints.NotNull" but is not initialized in this constructor*.

I can resolve it by initializing the field with default value ( [see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351878/object-is-marked-javax-validation-constraints-notnull-but-is-not-initialized-i/51734891#51734891) ) but it will make @NotNull annotation redundant. So my question is how to resolve this problem in best possible way.

```
public class Dummy {

    @NotNull(message = "Dummy field cannot be null")
    private Integer dummyField;

    public Dummy(Integer dummyField) {
        this.dummyField = dummyField;
    }

    public Integer getDummyField() {
        return dummyField;
    }

    public void setDummyField(Integer dummyField) {
        this.dummyField = dummyField;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should move the `@NotNull` annotations to the constructor and setter parameters:

```
public Dummy(@NotNull Integer dummyField) {
    this.dummyField = dummyField;
}
public void setDummyField(@NotNull Integer dummyField) {
    this.dummyField = dummyField;
}
```

If you verify that all possible mutators of that value only set it to non-null values, it's the same effect as stating that the value itself must be non-null - but *should* avoid the spurious warning